# Why do not the axes appear in this animation?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

In this animation the axes doesn´t appear, I don´t see something is missing in my code. I don`t know if the animation does that. I have tried two methods without getting solution. So what can be done to show the axes?

Thanks for the help.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])


n_drops = 100

rain_drops = np.zeros(n_drops, dtype=[('position', float, 2),
                                      ('size',     float, 1),
                                      ('growth',   float, 1),
                                      ('color',    float, 4)])



scat = ax.scatter(rain_drops['position'][:, 0], rain_drops['position'][:, 1], s=rain_drops['size'], lw=0.5, edgecolors=rain_drops['color'], facecolors='midnightblue',marker='s')



def update(frame_number):

    current_index = frame_number % n_drops

    rain_drops['size'] += rain_drops['growth']

    rain_drops['position'][current_index] = np.random.uniform(0, 0, 1)

    rain_drops['size'][current_index] = 5

    rain_drops['color'][current_index] = (0.05, 0.05, 0.09, 1)

    rain_drops['growth'][current_index] = 200 #np.random.uniform(50, 200)

    scat.set_edgecolors(rain_drops['color'])

    scat.set_sizes(rain_drops['size'])

    scat.set_offsets(rain_drops['position'])


animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=10)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue stems from your figure setup. One solution is to replace:

```
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
```

with:

```
ax = fig.add_axes([0.05, 0.05, 0.85, 0.85])
```

or the standard:

```
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_ylim(-1,1)
```

That gives me something that looks like this (a snapshot from somewhere in the middle of the animation):

[image]